# Properties cannot be used outside of try catch blocks

Tags: php, try-catch

I am trying to use properties inside try catch blocks.
The try catch blocks are inside classes.
I want to extend a specific class, making it the subclass of the class which handles exceptions.
The problem is, that when I try to use those variables from the subclass, it always says undefined. I have to delete both of classes in order to catch the properties. After reading some other answers here by adding a return statement (I added return 1) outside, inside of the try catch block, it doesn't seem to work and it always says undefined variable.
Any help?

The language is php

The source code **without** classes works perfect:

```
    try
    {
        //$pdo variable to insert PDO object information
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=studenti', 'root', '');

        //Set php to catch exceptions
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        //Set UTF-8 for character encodings
        $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
    }
    //Catch error if unable to connect
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        //error variable
        $error = 'Unable to connect with database. ' . $e->getMessage();

        //include file once and show on screen error message
        include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/inc/error.inc.php';
        //Exit and don't process further
        exit();
    }

    //Another Exception handling
    try
    {
        //Select statement
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM dega';
        $select = $pdo->query($sql);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        //error variable
        $error = 'Unable to select table. ' . $e->getMessage();

        //include file once and show on screen error message
        include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/inc/error.inc.php';

        //Exit and don't process further
        exit();
    }
```

The source code **with** classes doesn't work:

```
<?php
    //PDO class, connection with MySQL database
    class Connect
    {
        function connection()
        {
        $pdo = null;
            try
            {
                //$pdo variable to insert PDO object information
                $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=studenti', 'root', '');

                //Set php to catch exceptions
                $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                //Set UTF-8 for character encodings
                $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
            }
            //Catch error if unable to connect
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                //error variable
                $error = 'Unable to connect with database. ' . $e->getMessage();

                //include file once and show on screen error message
                include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/inc/error.inc.php';
                //Exit and don't process further
                exit();
            }
        }
    }

    class Select extends Connect
    {
        function selection()
        {
            //Another Exception handling
            try
            {
                //Select statement
                $sql = 'SELECT * FROM dega';
                $select = $pdo->query($sql);
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                //error variable
                $error = 'Unable to select table. ' . $e->getMessage();

                //include file once and show on screen error message
                include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/inc/error.inc.php';

                //Exit and don't process further
                exit();
            }
        }
    }

    //Output if successful
    $error = 'Database connection established.';
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/inc/error.inc.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have no subclass. [Object Inheritance](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php)
2. You have no properties. [Properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Read about [Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

---

```
class Connect
    {
    protected $pdo = null;

    public function connection()
        {
        $pdo = null;
        try
            {
            $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=studenti', 'root', '');
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
            } catch (PDOException $e)
            {
            $error = 'Unable to connect with database. ' . $e->getMessage();
            include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/inc/error.inc.php';
            exit();
            }
        }
    }

class Select extends Connect
    {

    function selection()
        {
        try
            {
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM dega';
            $select = $this->pdo->query($sql);
            } catch (PDOException $e)
            {
            $error = 'Unable to select table. ' . $e->getMessage();
            include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/inc/error.inc.php';
            exit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just extended, forgot to add it.
Even after declaring $pdo, it still doesn't work and it says undefined. I declare it as null.

Comment: @GSquadron, please, read documentation. You can get all needed information from there.

Comment: There is no way you can find on the documentation how to call Properties outside of try catch blocks. I have revised it before asking it here.

Comment: @GSquadron, answer updated. But you have serious trouble about reading documentation. Read and reread it again and again.

Comment: That is exactly what I did and it didn't work. I copy pasted your answer and still doesn't work. It says Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in... So I guess it's not my fault. I have no trouble reading and rereading. I tried another way, $this->pdo = $pdo; but it gives exact same result

Answer (score 0):

Put `$pdo` just before `connection()`:

```
class Connect
{
    protected $pdo = null; // or var $pdo = null;
    function connection()
    {
     ...
```

Inside the function it's a local variable not a class level property.

**EDIT**:
PHP requires `$this-><class-variable>` to access class properties inside functions. (Check out @Sectus's answer below.) Just using $pdo is creating a local variable on the fly (in both the methods) but gives an error in only `selection()` because that's where `query()` is being invoked without initializing a `PDO()` object first.

Comment: Just did that and it still says the same thing:
Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in...
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in...
Both are on the same line, which means the $pdo has something wrong